# Is there a limit to how many UIApplicationShortcutItems you can have?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7, 3dtouch

I want to add the new 3D/Force Touch feature (UIApplicationShortcutItem) to my app but I was wondering whether there is or isn't a limit to how many you can have on a single app?

I've had a look on the documentation but don't see a mention of a limit: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutItem_class/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iOS 9 displays up to four Home screen quick actions for your app. Within this limit, the system shows your static quick actions first, starting at the topmost position in the menu. If your static items do not exhaust the limit and you have also defined dynamic quick actions, then one or more of your dynamic quick actions is displayed.

You can refer to the [Apple’s sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/ApplicationShortcuts/Introduction/Intro.html)
.

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH1-SW1)

Comment: "Topmost" as in closest to the icon. The quick action popup will align itself according to the inverse position of the icon on the screen. The position of the action icons will alternate from left and right aligned depending on which half of the screen the icon resides (the app on the left half will show the action icon on the left side, and vice versa).